# PHP ODBC Connection to a SQL server from Ubuntu

Tags: php, sql, odbc

My host is a ubuntu machine 20.04 I'm using PHP 7.4 with `PDO_ODBC` installed

The goal is to be able to access to a SQL database who is using Windows credential on a ubuntu machine.

This is my `/etc/odbc.ini` file :

```
[msodbcsql]
Description=SQL Server driver
Driver=/usr/lib/libmsodbcsql-17.so

[pds_database]
Driver=msodbcsql
Description=PDS database access
Server=<server ip>\PDS
Port=1433
```

When I run `tsql -S pds_database -U <domain>\\<user> -P<passqord>`
I get this promt :
`1>`

I presume my `pds_database` connection is setup correctly ...

now, This is my PHP code :

`$db = new PDO ("odbc:pds_database", '<domain>\<user>', '<password>');`

I get the following error exception :

`"SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified"`

Do you have any idea what I missed during this connection ?

PS :
`/usr/lib/libmsodbcsql-17.so` is a symbolic link to `/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.7.so.2.1`
What is mean I'm running a `libmsodbcsql` 64 bits like my PHP

Comment: An error message is quite obvious. Take a look here: [Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (Linux)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I'm sorry @MaciejLos, but it's not that mush obvious ...

Comment: The installer for msodbcsql17 should have added an [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] in /etc/odbcinst.ini , so try using `DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` in your DSN entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've the exactly same problem with you

and I'm gonna share my full code about connection .php

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

// define variables;
/* $servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = ""; */

// Create connection
try {

    // THIS IS OLD WRONG CODE, PLEASE CHECK BELOW
    $DSN = 'odbc:Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};
        Server=192.168.X.X,1234\\MSSQLSERVER;Database=db_um_1699;
        Trusted_Connection=yes';

    $dbconn = new PDO($DSN, 'username', 'userPassword');
    
    $dbconn -> setattribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    $dbconn -> setattribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    "BRIDGE BUILD! \n <hr />";// Check connection

}catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Broke: ". $e->getMessage();
}
```

And yet I'm still using old way to connecting which is a mess and so difficult to operated.

---

12-16-2021 edit:

I was changed `odbc:driver` to `odbc:FreeTDS`
that worked!

first assume we all had odbc drivers;
we need to edit `odbc.ini` file in `/etc/odbcinst.ini`

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = ODBC for FreeTDS
Driver64    = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so
Setup64     = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so
FileUsage   = 1
```

next try to build the connection:

```
// Create connection
try {

    // CHANGE ODBC to FREETDS
    $DSN = 'odbc:Driver={FreeTDS};
        Server=192.168.X.X,1234\\MSSQLSERVER;Database=db_um_1699;
        Trusted_Connection=yes';

    $dbconn = new PDO($DSN, 'username', 'userPassword');
    
    $dbconn -> setattribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    $dbconn -> setattribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    "BRIDGE BUILD! \n <hr />";// Check connection

}catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Broke: ". $e->getMessage();
}
```

hope this information would be anyone who was same problem I had

but this still maybe not the good enough for all kind similar problem
since our database really aged which was `MS-sql-2008`